# How do I indent query output based on "depth"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine a table like:

```
create table test (depth integer, name text);
```

Add some rows:

```
insert into test (depth, name)
values (0, "no indent"), (1, "single indent"), (2, "double indent");
```

Now, create output based on the `depth` parameter that looks like this:

```
no indent
    single indent
        double indent
```

Where the indent in this case is 4 spaces (but could be changed to any interesting indent like a tab character).

My gut wants to do something like this:

```
select '    ' * depth || name from test order by depth;
```

However, this blows up in Postgres. String multiplication like this works as expected in Python. However, I'm unfamiliar with an equivalent operation in Postgres. Other database implementations would be interesting also.

Comment: According to (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) there is `REPEAT` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(name, (4 * depth) + length(name), ' ')
from test 
order by depth;
```

or `repeat()` plus concatenation:

```
select repeat('_', 4 * depth) || name
from test 
order by depth;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to Postgresql, but on SQL Fiddle leading spaces are automatically suppressed.

I changed space to underscore and it works.

My code (based on `REPEAT`):

```
select REPEAT(REPEAT('_', 4), depth) || name as "Column" from test order by depth;
```

Link to the SQL Fiddle with your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/96f11/4